# Optimization in R - nonlinear utility function with non-linear constraints

Tags: r, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Am trying to find vector `β` to maximize function

[image]

subject to 
(a)

[image]

and
(b) all elements of  `β` should be non-negative,

with `β, μ` are vectors of length 15, and `M` is a 15x15 covariance matrix (`μ` and `M` are given).

Any advice on which of the optimizers listed on [Stefan Theussl's CRAN page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) would be most suited for my case?

Comment: Have you tried DEoptim? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DEoptim/index.html

Comment: You could have a look at the 'limsolve' package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/limSolve/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach :

```
library(DEoptim)

fn_Beta <- function(beta, mu, val_M, val_K)
{
  M <- val_M
  K <- val_K
  num <- tryCatch(t(beta) %*% mu, error = function(e) NA)
  den <- tryCatch(sqrt(t(beta) %*% M %*% beta), error = function(e) NA)
  
  if(is.na(num) | is.na(den))
  {
    return(10 ^ 30)
    
  }else
  {
    val <- - num / den
    
    if(den > K)
    {
      return(10 ^ 30)
      
    }else
    {
      return(val)
    }
  }
}

mu <- runif(15)
M <- diag(rep(1, 15))
M[2, 1] <- 0.9
M[1, 2] <- 0.9
K <- 50

obj_DEoptim <- DEoptim(fn = fn_Beta, lower = rep(-10, 15), upper = rep(10, 15),
                       mu = mu, val_M = M, val_K = K, control = list(itermax = 2000))
```